# Joining on different columns from multiple tables and combining the results; Union method is too costly, need alternative approach - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, union, multiple-columns

There are two massive tables from where I have to query out a subset of interest. Both have multiple common columns but with lot of nulls. I want to join with multiple join conditions on these columns and then combine the result sets. Using Union method is costing too much and db is not ready to allow the query. Could someone help how I can optimize with some smart technique.

My query is like

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from  tab1 T1
left join tab2 T2 on T1.col1=T2.col1
Union
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from  tab1 T1
left join tab2 T2 on T1.col2=T2.col2
Union
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from  tab1 T1
left join tab2 T2 on T1.col3=T2.col3
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: If you don't care about duplicates, what about `union all`?

Comment: Please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query.  Or if it never finishes, then just an `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: "where I have to query out a subset of interest"  Your query has no filter conditions.  In what way is it a subset?  Every row of tab1 gets returned 3 times.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name , I knew Union All will reduce the load, but didn't try thinking the optimization won't be that high. The query takes now 1/1000th of the original cost. Thanks a ton for your suggestion. Cheers :)